# jqGrid client side filter not working

Tags: filter, jqgrid

This is my code. I have custom search fields and buttons. Grid should load json data by default. Based on search fields, it should reload on search click. Both ways, filter is not working.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var emptyMsgDiv = $('<div>No records found. Please refine your search and try again.</div>');

    $("#requestGrid").jqGrid({
        datatype: "json",
        mtype: 'POST',
        loanonce: true,
        url: '@Url.Action("PerformRequestSearch", "FactoryRequest")',
        postData: {
            ccnID: function () {
                return $('#ddlCCN option:selected').val();
            },
            facilityID: function () {
                return $('#ddlfacility option:selected').val();
            },
            keyType: function () {
                return $('#ddlKeyType option:selected').text();
            },
            fromDate: function () {
                var fromDate = document.getElementById("dateFrom").value;
                return fromDate;
            },
            toDate: function () {
                var toDate = document.getElementById("dateTo").value;
                return toDate;
            },
        },
        colNames: ["CCN", "Facility", "Dell Part#", "Key Type", "Quantity", "Status", "Action", "Comment", "CustomName", "messageid", "CCNID", "FacilityID"],
        colModel: [
            {
                name: "CCNName", index: "ccnname", width: 50, align: "right", editable: false
            },
            { name: "FacilityName", width: 50, align: "right", editable: false },
            { name: "DellPartNumber", width: 60, align: "right", editable: false },
            { name: "KeyTypeDescription", width: 60, align: "right", editable: false },
            { name: "Quantity", formatter: "integer", width: 60, align: "right", editable: false },
            { name: "Status", width: 60, align: "right", editable: false },
            {
                name: "ActionValue", width: 40, align: "center",
                sortable: true,
                align: 'center',
                editable: true,
                cellEdit: true,
                edittype: "select",
                formatter: 'select',
                search: false,
                editoptions: {
                    value: statusList,
                    dataEvents: [{
                        type: 'change',
                        fn: function (e) {
                            var grid = $("#requestGrid");
                            var selRowId = grid.jqGrid("getGridParam", "selrow");
                            var rowData = grid.jqGrid("getRowData", selRowId);
                            //var cm = grid.jqGrid("getColProp", selRowId, "Remark");
                            var selectDOM = e.target,
                                selectedOptionDOM = selectDOM.options[selectDOM.selectedIndex];

                            switch (selectedOptionDOM.value) {
                                case "0":
                                    grid.jqGrid('setColProp', selRowId, 'Remark', { editable: false });
                                    break;
                                case "1":
                                    grid.jqGrid('setColProp', selRowId, 'Remark', { editable: false });
                                    break;
                                case "2":
                                    grid.jqGrid('setColProp', selRowId, 'Remark', { editable: true });
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                    }]
                }
            },
            { name: "Remark", width: 70, align: "right", edittype: "textarea", search: false, editoptions: { rows: "2", cols: "30" }, editable: false },
            {
                name: 'CustomName', index: 'CustomName', width: 120, sortable: false, search: true, editable: false, hidden: true
            },
            {
                name: 'messageID', width: 120, sortable: false, editable: false, hidden: true
            },
            { name: "CCNID", width: 40, align: "center", editable: false, sortable: false, hidden: true },
            { name: "FacilityID", width: 60, align: "center", editable: false, sortable: false, hidden: true },
        ],
        cmTemplate: {
            editable: true, searchoptions: { clearSearch: false }, dataInit: function (elem) {
                $(elem).height(18);
            }
        },
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [5, 10, 20],
        pager: "#pagerFactoryReq",
        rownumbers: true,
        autoencode: true,
        ignoreCase: true,
        sortname: "CCNName",
        viewrecords: true,
        sortorder: "desc",
        caption: "ODM PO Approval",
        height: "100%",
        emptyrecords: 'No records found. Please refine your search and try again.',
        loadComplete: function () {
            var count = $("#requestGrid").getGridParam();
            var ts = $("#requestGrid")[0];
            if (ts.p.reccount === 0) {
                $("#requestGrid").hide();
                emptyMsgDiv.show();
            } else {
                $("#requestGrid").show();
                emptyMsgDiv.hide();
            }
        },
        autowidth: true,
        grouping: true,
        gridview: true,
        groupingView: {
            groupField: ['CustomName'],
            groupColumnShow: [false],
            groupText: ["<b>{0}<b>"],
            groupOrder: ["asc"],
            groupCollapse: true,
            groupDataSorted: true
        },
        onSelectRow: editRow
    }).jqGrid("navGrid", "#pagerFactoryReq", { add: false, edit: false, del: false, search: true, refresh: true }, {
        multipleSearch: true,
        overlay: false,
        onClose: function () {
            // if we close the search dialog during the datapicker are opened
            // the datepicker will stay opened. To fix this we have to hide
            // the div used by datepicker
            $("div#ui-datepicker-div.ui-datepicker").hide();

        }
    }).jqGrid("filterToolbar", { stringResult: true, defaultSearch: "cn" });
    jQuery("#requestGrid").navButtonAdd('#pagerFactoryReq', {
        caption: "",
        buttonicon: "ui-icon-disk",
        title: "Submit",
        onClickButton: function () {
            if (confirm('Are you sure to proceed?')) {
                var requestGridData = $("#requestGrid").jqGrid("getRowData");
                var dataToSend = JSON.stringify(requestGridData);
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '@Url.Action("UpdateRequests", "FactoryRequest")',
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: dataToSend,
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (message) {
                        $("#SuccessMessage").html(message[0]);
                        $("#ErrorMessage").html(message[1]);
                    },
                    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        $("#ErrorMessage").html(jqXHR + " " + textStatus + " " + errorThrown);
                    }
                });
            }
            else { alert('Cancelled'); }
        },
        position: "last"
    });
    // place div with empty message insde of bdiv
    emptyMsgDiv.insertAfter($("#requestGrid").parent());
});

var statusList = { '0': 'Select', '1': 'Approve', '2': 'Reject' };
function GetFacility(objCCN) {
    var procemessage = "<option value='0'>Please wait...</option>";
    $("#ddlfacility").html(procemessage).show();
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("GetFacilityByCCNId", "FactoryRequest")',
        data: { objCCN: objCCN },
        cache: false,
        type: "POST",
        success: function (data) {
            var markup = "<option value='0'>--Select Facility--</option>";
            for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
                markup += "<option value=" + data[x].Value + ">" + data[x].Text + "</option>";
            }
            $("#ddlfacility").html(markup).show();
        },
        error: function (reponse) {
            alert("error : " + reponse);
        }
    });
}

function ResetDropDownList() {
    $("select").each(function () { this.selectedIndex = 0 });
}

function ResetGrid() {
    jQuery("#requestGrid").jqGrid("clearGridData", true);
}

function ValidateDate() {
    var today = new Date();
    var test = today.getDate();

    var startDate = document.getElementById("dateFrom").value;
    var endDate = document.getElementById("dateTo").value;


    if (startDate !== "") {
        if ((startDate.match(/^\d\d?\/\d\d?\/\d\d\d\d$/))) {

        }
        else {
            alert("Kindly provide a valid start date format(MM/DD/YYYY)");
            document.getElementById(startDateTextBox).focus();
            return false;
        }
    }
    if (endDate !== "") {
        if ((endDate.match(/^\d\d?\/\d\d?\/\d\d\d\d$/))) {

        }
        else {
            alert("Kindly provide a valid end date format(MM/DD/YYYY)");
            document.getElementById(endDateTextBox).focus();
            return false;
        }
    }

    if (new Date(endDate) < new Date(startDate)) {
        alert("Kindly enter the end date greater than or equal to start date.");
        document.getElementById("dateTo").select();
        document.getElementById("dateTo").focus();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

$('#btnSearch').click(function () {
    var fromDate = document.getElementById("dateFrom").value;
    var toDate = document.getElementById("dateTo").value;
    if (ValidateDate()) {
        var selectedKeyType, selectedCCNID, selectedCCNName, selectedFacilityID, selectedFacilityName;
        if ($('#ddlCCN option:selected').val() != 0) {
            selectedCCNID = $('#ddlCCN option:selected').val();
            selectedCCNName = $('#ddlCCN option:selected').text();
        }
        if ($('#ddlfacility option:selected').val() != 0) {
            selectedFacilityID = $('#ddlfacility option:selected').val();
            selectedFacilityName = $('#ddlfacility option:selected').text();
        }
        if ($('#ddlKeyType option:selected').text() != "-- Select --")
            selectedKeyType = $('#ddlKeyType option:selected').text();
        jQuery("#requestGrid").clearGridData(true);
        jQuery("#requestGrid").jqGrid('setGridParam',
            {
                datatype: "json", postdata: null,
                postdata: { ccnID: selectedCCNID, facilityID: selectedFacilityID, keyType: selectedKeyType, fromDate: fromDate, toDate: toDate },
                search:true
            });
        jQuery("#requestGrid")[0].refreshIndex();
        jQuery("#requestGrid").trigger("reloadGrid");
    }
});

$(function () {
    // This will make every element with the class "date-picker" into a DatePicker element
    $('.date-picker').datepicker();
});

var lastSelection;
function editRow(id) {
    if (id && id !== lastSelection) {
        var grid = $("#requestGrid");
        grid.jqGrid('restoreRow', lastSelection);
        var dropdownSelval = jQuery('#requestGrid').getCell(id, 'ActionValue');
        var statusValue = jQuery('#requestGrid').getCell(id, 'Status');
        if (statusValue == "-") {
            if (dropdownSelval == "2") {
                $(this).jqGrid('setColProp', 'ActionValue', { editable: true });
                $(this).jqGrid('setColProp', 'Remark', { editable: true });
            }
            else {
                $(this).jqGrid('setColProp', 'ActionValue', { editable: true });
                $(this).jqGrid('setColProp', 'Remark', { editable: false });
            }
        }
        else {
            $(this).jqGrid('setColProp', 'ActionValue', { editable: false });
            $(this).jqGrid('setColProp', 'Remark', { editable: false });
        }
        grid.jqGrid('editRow', id, {
            keys: true,
        });
        lastSelection = id;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please refer this link for the complete script code,

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/47a977968e2aa6f9aab6f5885e8221d4

Comment: Please include always the information about **the version** of jqGrid, which you use (can use), and **the fork** of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jaGrid in version <=4.7). Your code contains many small (and not small) errors. For example, you use wrong parameters of `setGridParam` before reloading, you use wrong parameters of `navGrid`, you use different `index` and `name` values of `colModel` (`name: "CCNName", index: "ccnname"`) together with local data (`loadonce: true`)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

loanonce:true  to loadonce:true, . it will filter your data locally.

Comment: Yeah typo mistake. My bad. Thanks.